# Problems when add "s" to a nouns/verbs

Tags: orthography

My horse paints beautiful photos. {Here I understand why the "s" is used}

These pigs usually cook[s] dinner. {Why the "s" isn't used here?}

Your dog, cat and chicken get[s] along well. {Neither here}

P.S. I'm learning English by my own, so any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In English, you can usually make a plural by adding 's' or 'es' to the singular. You might expect the verb ending to do the same thing, but it does the opposite. She jumps and the horse jumps, but *they jump*.
One thing does, many things do. That's how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough.
all of these sentences are said in the Present Simple tense.

When the subject of such sentences is a singular third person( e.g. he,she,it any singular noun, etc.) the verb (the infinitive verb) is added the **S** syllable( take notice there are different spelling rules).

So, the first sentence: the subject is a *horse*= it or he.

Second sentence: pigs are plural.

*your dog, car and chicken* is a compound subject i.e. plural.

Good luck on your endeavor